Why the text alignment of list items are offset in safari browser in iOS or Mac OS while using prose class?

This is the example preview of what im getting in my safari browser when there is a list included in my text, this is a markdown rendered text and the classname for that component is,
className="prose prose-neutral max-w-[unset] text-sm prose-p:leading-relaxed prose-pre:p-0 md:text-base"

all browsers dont have this problem, but safari has this alignment issue with the list items only, is there any fix or workaround for this?
I tried to fix it by changing the styles for all the li items in the prose class
